# JWPlayer playing video

Tags: video, scripting, flv, jwplayer

I am currently using JWPlayer to play FLV video on a web page. How do I seek to specific parts of the video:

(a) While it is playing?
(b) Before it has loaded?

Generally speaking - what is the best method for frame-by-frame manipulation of FLV files?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Max.

Comment: "what is the best method for frame-by-frame manipulation of FLV files?".. in JWPlayer or in general?

Comment: Either in JWPlayer or in general. Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `player.seek(pos:Number)` method documented in the API.

http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player5Api